# Retrieve value of cookie from another page in JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a form http://evmyf.vzhgw.servertrust.com/Articles.asp?ID=257

On the form I have a link called upload logo. It opens a window to upload an image. I have stored the image name that is uploaded in the window in a cookie. The cookie name is UploadFile. I want to retrieve the value of the cookie on the link I mentioned above. How can I do it? Please advise.

On the upload logo page that is the new window, I have created the cookie and stored its value using following code in ASP.

```
Response.Cookies("UploadFile")=File.FileName
fname=Request.Cookies("UploadFile")
response.write("UploadFile=" & fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

This library will allow you to grab a cookie using jQuery:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

To retrieve a cookie:

```
var my_cookie_value = $.cookie('UploadFile');
```

To create a cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Comment: i used the above code in the document.ready function but it is not getting called. please advise.

Comment: Can you confirm that your cookie is getting created? You can do this by inspecting cookies in your browser settings. I'm also assuming that you're trying to retrieve the cookie from an application in the same domain as where you set the cookie.

Comment: yes the cookie is getting created. yes i am retriving cookie in the same site.

Comment: Try creating a cookie in jQuery and then retrieving it. I've update my answer to show you how to do this. Are you able to retrieve the new jQuery created cookie? Can you also add your jQuery code to your question too please.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
jQuery.cookie(name_of_cookie);
```

or using a global document.cookie to find Your cookie